# LiPo cell as RTC backup battery

Tags: diodes, low-power, battery-operated, rtc

I am wondering what is the sensible way of using the LiPo cell that powers a handheld device to also act as the RTC backup battery for the MCU. There is charging circuitry for the LiPo cell on-board as well.

`Vbat` spec, from the MCU datasheet:

`VBAT range: 1.8 to 3.6 V, power supply for RTC, external clock 32 kHz oscillator and backup registers (through power switch) when VDD is not present.`

The battery is a fairly typical 1-cell LiPo, with the following specs:

[image]

So if I connect the LiPo cell to `Vbat` directly, there might be up to 4.2V present on that pin. According to the datasheet, this probably should be avoided:

[image]

Using a diode, or two perhaps, to drop battery voltage down is an easy option.

Here's the catch, as far as I can see: `Vf` depends on `If`, and with the miniscule amount of current drawn on that pin `Vf` might not be very high? Looking at a generic diode datasheet:

[image]

`Vf` is 1V, at 10mA `If`. Presumably, and hopefully, the MCU will not go anywhere near that amount and stay in uA range, which presumably will reduce the `Vf`?

Alternatively, placing a high enough (100k?) resistor between the LiPo and `Vbat` terminal and letting the MCU pad diodes deal with clamping is also an option. This feels more adventurous than the first option.

Wondering what's the best way to go about it, comments appreciated.

Comment: Which MCU it is (could be STM32)? How much it consumes current from Vbat? The resistor solution will fail because Vbat is a supply pin itself, it likely has no clamping to anywhere.

Comment: @Justme Good point about no clamping, thanks. It is a GD32 MCU, very similar to STM32 from what I can tell. Battery supply current (Ibat) is specified to be between 0.4 and 2.2uA. As expected, fairly little amount.